# How to deploy Tensorflow service in a server

Tags: web-services, tensorflow, aws-lambda

I successfully trained a deep net using tensorflow. The net is able to modify the content of a square 512x512 px image.

Now I would like to deploy the net in a server and create a basic service. Something like this: https://letsenhance.io/. Where a user (client) can send a picture and the server respond with a modified picture.

I read a lot of tutorials about AWS Lambda, but my problem is that the model data (weights) is very big: 700 MB, and seems to exceed the Lambda limitation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

So I can use Lambda? Or exist an alternative and better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It will exceed the limitations of AWS Lambda.

But you can try running on [EC2 instance with GPU support](https://ramhiser.com/2016/01/05/installing-tensorflow-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-gpu-support/) but it will take some time to set it up. Also, it costs much more than running lambdas.

I've heard about [TensorFlow on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/tensorflow/) but I haven't tried it.